# A-Frame performance issue in Chrome?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have been working on an A-Frame demo ([code on Github](https://github.com/MasterFelix15/A-Builder)). There seems to be huge performance difference when I run my project in different browsers. I am only getting <10fps in Chrome when I am getting a solid 60fps in either Firefox or Safari. Does anybody know what is causing this performance drop? I need to use Chrome for its SpeechRecognition API, for SpeechRecognition does not work in Firefox for the time being.

Comment: I tried hitting your github demo link https://felixdemo.fun/ and it didn't work.. if you get it working, I can take a look. There are a bunch of debugging/profiling tools built into the chrome debugger..

Comment: The demo would be accessible at http://www.felixdemo.fun/demo/A-Builder/ . It is fine at first after loaded, but once you put down a pin on the ground by mouse click or screen touch, the fps drops straight from 60 to 7fps.

Comment: The weird thing is... it works fine on mobile version of Chrome for some reason. Just not the desktop version of Chrome..

Comment: Are you using a laptop or have integrated graphics?

Comment: I have discrete graphics. But I don't think that is relevant. It is not a heavy duty application, as I mentioned, it works fine on mobile Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The default sky is too heavy, try setting segmentsHeight and segmentsRadius to a very small number.